# Speeding up point-in-polygon for Python

Tags: collision-detection, python, optimization

In researching collision detection methods for non-Rect-like objects I came across point-in-polygon -- specifically, the even-odd rule.

The one presently on Wikipedia claims it is written in Python, but it is a little bit pedantic:

```
# x, y -- x and y coordinates of point
# a list of tuples [(x, y), (x, y), ...]
def isPointInPath(x, y, poly):
    num = len(poly)
    i = 0
    j = num - 1
    c = False
    for i in range(num):
            if  ((poly[i][1] > y) != (poly[j][1] > y)) and \
                    (x < (poly[j][0] - poly[i][0]) * (y - poly[i][1]) / (poly[j][1] - poly[i][1]) + poly[i][0]):
                c = not c
            j = i
    return c
```

This didn't particularly remind me of Python, so I spent my lunch break working on this. I don't consider myself a master chef optimizer, but I came up with something slightly more attractive:

```
def fast_pt_in(pt, poly):
    testX, testY = pt
    last = -1
    answer = False
    for now in xrange(0, len(poly)):
        nowX, nowY = poly[now]
        lastX, lastY = poly[last]
        if (nowY > testY) != (lastY > testY) and (testX < (lastX - nowX) * (testY - nowY)/(lastY - nowY) + nowX):
            answer = not answer
        last += 1
    return answer
```

A couple of `cProfile` tests reveal mine to be faster - both when returning True and False - when done 2**16 times (I figure… 60 FPS, 20 minutes of gameplay, assuming it's brute forcing the collisions without other things to prevent overchecking of course).

In the example below the 'old version' is `pt_in` and the new version is `fast_pt_in`. `cProfile` is executing the following:

```
cProfile.run("shp = [(x, y) for x in (10, 30) for y in (10, 30)]; [func(point, shape) for x in range(0, 2**16)]")
```

where `func` is either function, and `point` is either one inside the shape (15,15) or outside(5, 5).

```
Stick$ python pt_in.py

---TRUE hit in Rect---
=== fast_pt_in ===
         131075 function calls in 0.211 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.021    0.021    0.211    0.211 <string>:1(<module>)
    65536    0.184    0.000    0.188    0.000 pt_in.py:64(fast_pt_in)
    65536    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {range}


=== pt_in ===
         196611 function calls in 0.312 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.021    0.021    0.312    0.312 <string>:1(<module>)
    65536    0.266    0.000    0.291    0.000 pt_in.py:1(pt_in)
    65536    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    65537    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {range}


---FALSE hit in Rect---
=== pt_in ===
         196611 function calls in 0.173 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.021    0.021    0.173    0.173 <string>:1(<module>)
    65536    0.126    0.000    0.152    0.000 pt_in.py:1(pt_in)
    65536    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    65537    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {range}


=== fast_pt_in ===
         131075 function calls in 0.145 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.021    0.021    0.145    0.145 <string>:1(<module>)
    65536    0.119    0.000    0.123    0.000 pt_in.py:64(fast_pt_in)
    65536    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
```

And that's just with Rect-like shapes; as the number of points in the polygon increases, mine eeks out further and further ahead.

This is all well and good, but I want to make sure I'm getting a lot out of this one. Are there any further changes I can make to this (apart from refactoring it into C, lulz) to eek a little more out of it? I believe I am assigning variables as efficiently as possible to get repeated lookup out of the loop unlike the original, but apart from that I am uncertain if there are other reasonable changes to make.

**EDIT**: The use of `xrange` prompts me to clarify - I'm using Python 2.7.

Bonus question -- I'm right, right; that Wiki example is super-unpythonic. Should I replace it? :/

Comment: Resources: http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/, http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/ptpoly_haines/

Comment: Which Python version are you using? The wikipedia version uses the range function which will create a list with all elements in Python version 2.7.x and below. In Python 3+ range returns an iterator function only creating one element during iterator. Your code uses xrange instead, a function only available in Python 2. Try running both in python 3.

Comment: Ooh I guess I need to specify, my bad :/ :/ Python 2.7

Comment: Ok try running the wikipedia code with xrange instead of range.

Answer (score 2):

Before testing for performance, test for correctness. The way you have defined your shape in the test results in wrong answers:

```
shp = [(x, y) for x in (10, 30) for y in (10, 30)]
```

This results in the following shape:

```
[(10, 10), (10, 30), (30, 10), (30, 30)]
```

If you plot this, you will notice it looks like this:

```
(10, 30)  (30, 30)
      B----D
      |    |
      A----C
(10, 10)  (30, 10)
```

The polygon `A-B-C-D` is not a convex polygon. What you want instead is `A-B-D-C`:

```
shape = [(10, 10), (10, 30), (30, 30), (30, 10)]
```

Now we have a shape that is a convex polygon, and we can use your two points for verification:

```
inside = (15, 15)
outside = (5, 5)
```

To make it easier to compare both functions, I've changed the signature of `isPointInPath` to be the same as `fast_pt_in` and just unpack `pt` to `x` and `y` in the first line (the rest of the code is the same):

```
def isPointInPath(pt, poly):
    x, y = pt
    # ... rest of the code ...
```

And because we can possibly have multiple candidates, let's define a global list of functions that we test:

```
candidates = [isPointInPath, fast_pt_in]
```

Now, we can use nosetests to write a unit test. What we want to check is that the function returns `True` when given `inside` and `shape` as parameters and `False` when given `outside` and `shape` as parameters (read up on [test generators](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators) in the nose docs to find out how this test works):

```
def test_correctness():
    def test_call(func, point, shape, result):
        assert func(point, shape) == result

    for func in candidates:
        yield test_call, func, inside, shape, True
        yield test_call, func, outside, shape, False
```

Assuming we have both functions, and those variables (`shape`, `inside`, `outside`, `candidates`) in a file `point_in_poly.py`, then we can run it with nosetests (use `pip install nose` to install nose if you don't have it yet):

```
% python -m nose point_in_poly.py -v
point_in_poly.test_correctness(<function isPointInPath at 0x10a2aaaa0>, (15, 15), [(10, 10), (10, 30), (30, 30), (30, 10)], True) ... ok
point_in_poly.test_correctness(<function isPointInPath at 0x10a2aaaa0>, (5, 5), [(10, 10), (10, 30), (30, 30), (30, 10)], False) ... ok
point_in_poly.test_correctness(<function fast_pt_in at 0x10ac272a8>, (15, 15), [(10, 10), (10, 30), (30, 30), (30, 10)], True) ... ok
point_in_poly.test_correctness(<function fast_pt_in at 0x10ac272a8>, (5, 5), [(10, 10), (10, 30), (30, 30), (30, 10)], False) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Ok, so now we can be sure the functions actually return a correct result for these test cases (if you set `shape` to your original definition, you see it failing).

Let's get to the performance test. For that, you don't need to use profile, Python provides a nice tool called [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). At the end of the file add the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                               
    import timeit                                                                                                        
    for func in candidates:                                                                                              
        duration = timeit.timeit('%s(%r, %r); %s(%r, %r)' % (func.__name__, inside, shape,                               
                                                             func.__name__, outside, shape),                             
                                 setup='from %s import %s' % (__name__, func.__name__))                                  
        print '%-30s: %.5fs' % (func.__name__, duration)
```

What this does is for each candidate function it calls the function with a point inside and one outside and run this 1000000 times and returns the number of seconds passed, then running it results in:

```
% python point_in_poly.py
isPointInPath                 : 3.21318s
fast_pt_in                    : 2.50431s
```

So yeah, `fast_pt_in` is a bit faster. Now, for the question about increasing performance: You can avoid having to use range together and just remember the last point, then you don't need to index into `poly` at all:

```
def faster_pt_in(pt, poly):                                                                                              
    testX, testY = pt                                                                                                    
    last = poly[-1]                                                                                                      
    answer = False                                                                                                       
    for now in poly:                                                                                                     
        nowX, nowY = now                                                                                                 
        lastX, lastY = last                                                                                              
        if (nowY > testY) != (lastY > testY) and (testX < (lastX - nowX) * (testY - nowY)/(lastY - nowY) + nowX):        
            answer = not answer                                                                                          
        last = now                                                                                                       
    return answer
```

Add this to `candidates` like so:

```
candidates = [isPointInPath, fast_pt_in, faster_pt_in]
```

Use nosetests to see if it still gives the right results (it does) and then run the performance check:

```
% python point_in_poly.py
isPointInPath                 : 3.22605s
fast_pt_in                    : 2.42880s
faster_pt_in                  : 1.72670s
```

Now of course there might be other improvements, but with this framework you should now be able to easily add new variants, see if they still do the right thing, and then compare their performance.